# Why aren't all complex exponentials equal to $1$, since $e^{2\pi ~i ~t} = ((e^{i\pi})^2)^{t} = ((-1)^2)^{t} = 1^{t} = 1$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I don't understand what is wrong with the following reasoning.  Can someone help me understand?
$f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ by $f(t) = e^{2\pi ~i ~t} = ((e^{i\pi})^2)^{t} = ((-1)^2)^{t} = 1^{t} = 1$

I don't see where the computation goes wrong, but it is obviously wrong somewhere.

Comment: $e^{2\pi i}=1$.

Comment: Maybe you will like this one better: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4475281/do-exponetial-identities-not-apply-for-negative-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^{yz}=(x^y)^z$ is only valid for $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and $y,z\in\mathbb{R}$.

For further information, have a look at [Question on roots of unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437748/question-on-roots-of-unity) .

Comment: I would like to know under which conditions does $x^{yz} = (x^y)^z$.   I don't think that is answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437748/question-on-roots-of-unity, at least not explicitly.  There was a comment above that this is only true if x is real.  However, it is sometimes not even true when x is real.

Comment: An alternative problem is that the complex exponential (and exponentials in general) only behave how we want them to (i.e. allowing breaking exponents into products) if we treat them as multivalued maps, and when viewed this way the problem is that $1^t$ is not identically $1$ unless $t$ in an integer.

Comment: @JimNewton One difficulty in answering that question is that it ultimately depends on how you define exponentials. However the only case where it is true independent of definition is if both $y$ and $z$ are integers then $x^{yz}=(x^y)^z$.

Comment: @Fishbane, as this post is marked a duplicate, I've created another question to address this issue (as suggested by the stackexchange duplication mechanism). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4495918/when-does-xyz-xyz